# How to copy symmetrically

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I want to first bring the center of the top face of vertical bar to the intersection point of the edges as I marked #1 (right now it is slightly off as I did it manually), and then copy the vertical bar symmetrically to the other side , where I marked #2 and x. So I will have two vertical bars inside the big rectangular prism, symmetrical with respect to center edge loop. How can I do this? (which I highlighted as visual aid now) [image]

Comment: Snap the cursor to the center loop, then set the cursor as a pivot.

Comment: Might also be worth using the Mirror modifier if it's going to be symmetrical.